# Immersions coming from projecting away from a line

Tags: gt.geometric-topology, differential-topology, smooth-manifolds

Let $M$ be a compact $n$-manifold embedded in $\Bbb R^{2n}$ with $n \ne 1$. There is a map $F:S(TM) \to \Bbb RP^{2n-1}$ by identifying $TM$ as a subspace of of $\Bbb R^{2n}$ under the embedding. It is very easy to see that projection away from a line $l$ is an immersion if and only if $l$ is not in the image of $F$.

A standard proof of the weak version of the immersion theorem from the weak version of the embedding can be done with the analysis of this map $F$, but in the above case $F$ is a map of $2n-1$-manifolds so may very well be surjective (and is in the case of the n-torus inside $\Bbb R^{2n}$ for instance). I have two questions about this map $F$.

1. Does there exist an embedding $M \to \Bbb R^{2n}$ so that $F$ is not surjective (preferably by modifying the original embedding)? An affirmative answer gives a proof of Whitney's strong immersion theorem, though after looking at the original paper Whitney appears to be doing something slightly different.
2. What can be said about the topological structure for $F$? In the case of (non-trivial) products of spheres it is relatively easy to see (just using a cup product argument) that the topological degree of $F$ is always zero. Is this always the case for any embedding?

A concrete interesting case of this is for embeddings $S^2 \to \Bbb R^4$. In this case, $F$ is a self map of $\Bbb RP^3$. I'd be very surprised if $F$ could be a diffeomorphism for some interestingly embedded $S^2$, but I do not know how to prove otherwise.